# skip timer in JavaScript interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I currently have a function that executes some code within a `setInterval` method. This is working as expected. The problem is I conditionally execute code within this timer. If the condition is not met it will still wait the timeout until trying again. Is there a way of 'skipping' the delay and only executing it when the condition is met.

You will notice in my demo there is a prolonged delay between outputting paragraph results 4 and 8 (as its delaying in between the checks). I would like there to be a consistent delay throughout the whole procedure.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/jdec4h0x/

```
var intAdd = setInterval(function() {
  refIndex++

  if(refIndex >= predefinedMaxLimit) {
    refIndex = 0;
    loopedThrough = true;
  }

  // if this exists then increment refIndex and try again
  if (loopedThrough || !$(".myclass[data-mydata1='" + predefinedData2 + "'][data-mydata2='" + refIndex + "']").length) {
    counter++;

    $('p').last().after('<p>IN Cond Ref = ' + refIndex + '</p>');


    // ** js code within this tiemout **

    if (counter >= predefinedOutputP) clearInterval(intAdd);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Of course, simply cancel the timer and make a new one with your new delay.

Comment: @KevinB that won't work. The timer is out of scope https://jsfiddle.net/jdec4h0x/1/.

Comment: Of course it will work, it's the only way it would be possible, you can't change/skip the delay of an existing timer. Your code currently has it set to run the interval 9 times before clearing the interval, which it is correctly doing.

Comment: @KevinB That doesn't seem very efficient at all - create a whole new `setInterval` function every time a condition is/isn't met? This could be dozens. If you have a logical concept please share an example.

Comment: I'd rather not. it's pretty simple, you can't change the delay of an interval, and you can't skip the delay, therefore there is only one solution; stop the interval and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the delay of the interval. Either you destroy and create an interval as Kevin B said or you use `setTimeout`, which you have to call every time anyway, and then use a delay or another depending on a condition.

```
/* ... */

if (conditionIsMet) intAdd = setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
else intAdd = setTimeout(function() {}, 1);

/* ... */
```

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdec4h0x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multjple approaches as pointed out by other users.

I would use `setTimeout`. I'd put this in a function that resides within a loop. You can do this with a `while` loop. This then gives the the ability to break out when the condition is met. you will need to increment the timer on each loop.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jdec4h0x/4/

```
while (progress) {
  refIndex++

  if (refIndex >= predefinedMaxLimit) {
    refIndex = 0;
    loopedThrough = true;
  }
  if (loopedThrough || !$(".myclass[data-mydata1='" + predefinedData2 + "'][data-mydata2='" + refIndex + "']").length) {
    counter++;
    myTimer = myTimer + 500;
    console.log(refIndex);

    myFunction(refIndex);

    if (counter >= predefinedOutputP) {
      $('p').last().after('<p>Cleared Interval</p>');
      progress = false;
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(ref) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('p').last().after('<p>IN Cond Ref = ' + ref + '</p>');
    // ** js code within this tiemout **
  }, myTimer)
}
```